# Ruby on Rails Project Timepicker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui-datepicker, timepicker

I am trying to use http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ timepicker. I have ruby 1.9.3p484 and rails 4.1.0 versions. I have included the jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css from the above website in my app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss. I have also copied jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js into app/assets/javascripts.

In my Gem File, I have added

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

In my app/assets/javascripts/application.js file I have added

```
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-ui-timepicker-addon

$( function(){
      $("#tpicker").timepicker();
      });
```

In my app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss I have added

```
*= require jquery-ui
```

and also the CSS from jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css (found at http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) at the bottom.

The problem is this. In my html.erb I have following

```
<%= f.text_field :time, id: "tpicker" %>
```

However, the timepicker does not show when clicked or typed in the given text_field. Please help!

Comment: is this a typo `$("tpicker").timepicker();` ? it should be       `$("#tpicker").timepicker();`.

Comment: I have fixed it in the question. It was a typo here, not in my actual .js file. Thanks for pointing it out here tho.

Comment: In the browser did you see the source of your page for the file which you have added are being included in the script tag and if included they are not being included twice?

Comment: @Deep I do not really understand. How can I check that? :p

Comment: @Deep i do see jquery-ui-timepicker.js in my page's source

Comment: @gmoney: so it is included only once right?

Comment: add it in your page rather than in application.js file.

Comment: as said by @Milind add the js function written by you in the page and then see the result

Comment: did that. The only change I noticed what that when I clicked on my text field, my page moved up a little :/ timepicker still doesnt show

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it should be something like this:

```
$( function(){
      $('#tpicker').timepicker();
      $('#tpicker').on('click', function (){
           $('#tpicker').timepicker('setTime', new Date());
         });
      });
```

for additional examples -- read this [jquery.timepicker demos and documentations](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/)

Comment: for debug, put `alert('click!)` into on_click_function and You can see have you event `click` or don't have... As case You could use `change` or other event... Some browsers don't like `click event` without `a` element...

Comment: I changed the function to this, 

     '$( function(){
            $('#tpicker').timepicker();
           $('#tpicker').on('click', function (){
           $('#tpicker').timepicker('setTime', new Date());
           alert("click");
});
});'

this is my field <%= f.text_field :time, id: "tpicker" %>. When clicked, nothing shows up

Answer (score 0):

So this is how it works. I included all the javascript in my page file inside  tags. It is working now, except for the fact that I have to refresh the page for it to work. It does not work the first time.